# $p_1^x + p_2^y = 2^z$ not possible?

Tags: number-theory

We have equation:

$p_1^x + p_2^y = 2^z$

$p_1$ and $p_2$ is odd prime numbers.

$x, y, z > 2$

This is a special case [Beal conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture).

I know that Beal conjecture is an open problem, but the above equation does not contain the whole problem.

Comment: I think it's impossible for odd $x,y$

Comment: Can you write a sketch of the proof?

Comment: By simple modulo 4 argument, it can be proven that $x,y$ cannot be both even.

Comment: It is known that $13^2+7^3=2^9$, and it is only known solution of Fermat-Catalan conjecture other than $1^m+2^3=3^2$

Comment: $x, y, z > 2$ :)

Comment: @Aurelio That's his point. The only known solutions in a more general sense do not meet your restrictions.